# Linking Jira with Lambda with a safe way to hide credentials

Tags: node.js, lambda, aws-lambda, jira

I need to automatically create issues on Jira when AWS-lambda is triggered.

I've done this and the code is working,

the problem is: There are multiple admins that can access the Lambda, and I can't leave my Jira credentials in the Lambda.
We are using the company's installation of Jira -and we can't get any different credentials to use for this.

Is there any workaround to not include my credentials?, or may be application to encode them -not in a way that anyone can decode it (e.g. base 64)

Any innovative ideas would be very much appreciated

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If other users have access to the AWS console with admin permissions, then there is no way for you to store the credentials in a way that they would not be able to access them.

The reason being that they could assume the same role as the Lambda function is using, or they will have access to the Lambda code so they can see what decryption key to use for any encrypted credentials.

There might be a solution where you create a new AWS account that only you have access to but is part of an organisational unit of the company so billing still gets roled up to the organisational master account, but I am not sure that you can lock that down in such a way that the company admin cannot access your account.
It will also depend on how you are accessing Jira with regards to any network rules that might have been setup. It might require VPC peering or similar.
Considering you cannot get a Jira account for operational stuff, I would assume that getting an extra AWS account is also out of the question.